# Having trouble serving both https://example.com and www.example.com on Apache2 on one host

Tags: apache, apache2, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I am serving my website (Angular App) on an Ubuntu machine on AWS. My domain  example.com is registered on GoDaddy. My website is served on AWS. I have set name servers on GoDaddy to point to AWS Route53 Hosted zone. On Route53 I have an A record for example.com along with TXT record. I am using Let's Encrypt for my ssl certificate. I am using Apache2 to serve my website. My https://example.com works fine on all browsers.

I created a CNAME record [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) on Route53 to route traffic to example.com. https://www.example.com works fine on Chrome (and on Edge). However, Safari and Firefox complains "site not found" if https://example.com is not cached. If that is cached, it complains "connection is not private".

I have tried different configurations:

1. in httpd.conf using ServerAlias
2. configuring separate VirtualHost one for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and the other for example.com with their own certificates
3. two separate hosted zones one for example.com and the other for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the issue. The issue was with the certificate generated.

Initially I was trying to generate two certs one with example.com and another with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
The actual error when I tried to access [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)  was: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN, and when I drilled down a bit more, I noticed the cert served was for example.com. On Chrome based browsers, it would switch to example.com and everything was happy. But, Safari and Firefox did not do that and was erring. Since the certs are not readable, it was hard to figure out from the cert itself.

The fix I did was to generate one cert that expand to honor both:

```
sudo certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d example.com -d www.example.com  --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 certonly
```